# Captions / Subtitles not working with video tag LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I'm trying to show subtitles / captions in the video tag that I've embedded in my HTML file. However, the captions don't show at all.

HTML:

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                <source src={videoUrl} type="video/mp4">
                <track src={myTrackFileUrl} kind="captions" srclang="en">
            </video>
```

JS:

```
connectedCallback() {
        this.videoUrl = 'xyz.amazonaws.com/myVideoPath';
        this.myTrackFileUrl = 'myTrackFileUrl'; //I earlier used xyz.amazonaws.com/myTrackFileUrl
    }
```

Earlier, I was getting **unsafe attempt to load url domains protocols and ports must match srt file html video tag "same path"** error when I was supplying the full url to the track src(captionFileUrl) and once I changed it to above as per answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581827/track-unsafe-attempt-to-load-url-from-frame-with-url) it stopped throwing this error in console but captions are still not showing in video. I've tried using both webvtt and srt files for track and none of them seem to be working.

I also tried setting the track mode to showing like below but even this does not have any effect.

```
renderedCallback() {
        this.template.querySelectorAll('video').forEach(item => {
            item.addEventListener('load', () => {
                let tracks = item.textTracks[0];
                tracks.mode = 'showing';  
            })
        })
}
```

Has anyone encountered such issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm trying to do something very similar and running into the same issue. 
I get the same error even when the video file and srt/vtt file are both stored as ContentDocument within Salesforce.
I can get the audio/video to play no problems, but when I attempt to enable subtitles, I get the error.